# The set of limit ordinals in $\omega_1$ is unbounded

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to prove that the set of limit ordinals in $\omega_1$, call it $L$, is unbounded. This result is intuitively clear, but explicitly showing this isn't as intuitive.

Toward a contradiction, suppose that $L$ is bounded. Then I know a couple of things follow:

- I know that countable sets are bounded, but are bounded sets countable?
- Because $L$ is the set of *limit* ordinals, we cannot suppose $\alpha = \sup L$ and use $\alpha +1$ as a contradiction

Any advice on how to do this? Is a contradiction best or is there a better method?

Answer (score 5):

Your idea of just using $\alpha+1$ works with a little modification: if $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal, then $\alpha+\omega$ is a countable limit ordinal.

I wouldn’t phrase this as a proof by contradiction but as a direct proof that the limit ordinals less than $\omega_1$ are unbounded.

Comment: I see. So since $\omega$ is a limit ordinal and since $\alpha$ is countable, then by how we defined $\omega$, then $\omega+ \alpha$ must also be a limit ordinal, right? How is this justification more fomally stated? I just want to be able to justify that first sentence formally

Comment: @DavidC.Huang No,  $\omega+\alpha$ is a limit ordinal if and only if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal (or $0$). By contrast, $\alpha+\omega$ is the least limit ordinal greater than $\alpha$. Look at the definition of ordinal addition: $\alpha+\omega= \sup_{n<\omega} (\alpha+n)$. (Whereas it is also apparent from the definition of ordinal addition that $\omega+\alpha$ is a successor whenever $\alpha$ is.)